# Compare values from two different tables and multiply them

Tags: sql-server

I couldn't think of a good enough title, however here is my question.

I have a few tables in an Application which along other things will generate a monthly bill for consumers of a power utility. Specifically there are three tables involved, 
1) Consumer Table
2) Billing History Table
3) Rate List Table

There are different price slabs per units consumed for different types of connections, for example a **Domestic connection** having consumed upto 50 units per month would a considerably lower bill then a Commercial connection consuming 50 units per month.

The structure is at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eeab6

The application_nature field in the Consumers table defines what type of connection it is  COMMERCIAL OR DOMESTIC.

The payment_status in the billing_history2 table stores a boolean value indicating whether or not a bill has been paid.

Using this query i generate the total consumption of a Consumer and arrears if any.

```
SELECT BILLING_HISTORY2.CONSUMER_ID, count(reading) AS 'DEFAULT PERIOD', SUM(reading) AS 'Total Reading'  from BILLING_HISTORY2 where payment_status=0 GROUP by billing_history2.CONSUMER_ID;
```

What i want here is to generate 
1) a monthly bill based upon the total units consumed since the last bill paid.
2) A Monthly bill based upon the total units consumed since the month and then add arrears to it.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1) Lookup when the last bill was paid. Something like:

```
SELECT FROM BILLING_HISTORY2 where ID = 'CUSTOMERIDHERE' ORDER BY READING_MONTH_YEAR DESC
```

2) Take that first record's date variable and lookup all the readings for customer that came on or after that date (this assumes people pay up to the current day's charge).

3) Then, as you loop through each record that matches the criteria from Step 2, add the total charges together in variables.

4) Next, if 'payment_status' indicates the previous bill has not been paid, repeat steps 1-3, making sure to ignore the previous month's date's record (and getting the month BEFORE THAT). Also, only search for values within a date range. So if the previous bill started Feb. 1, your range of the previous month should be Jan. 1-Jan. 31. And then if that bill wasn't paid, search for charges between Dec. 1-Dec. 31. Basically, you need to keep going back 1 month at a time until you find a paid bill (or non-existant one, implying no service before then) and adding the values you find to an overall total.

Comment: Created a view of the query VIEW_CUSTOMER_BILL that i posted in my question AND THEN __SELECT vmctu.[Total Reading],p2.price,vmctu.[Total Reading]* p2.price AS 'BILL'  from VIEW_CUSTOMER_BILL vmctu  
INNER JOIN price_list2 p2 ON vmctu.application_nature=p2.flag AND vmctu.[Total Reading] BETWEEN p2.limit_start AND p2.limit_end __ gives me the Bill along with the arrears. However this takes into account the whole sum of units consumed that have not been paid for

Comment: The view that i designed doesn't work correctly, since it doesn't subtract the paid amount.

Comment: My solution only relies on SQL for basically yanking data out of the system. You'll probably want to do your variable comparisons and adding/subtracting/multiplying in whatever programming language you're using. There's only so much you can [easily] do natively within a DB.

Comment: Making comparisons using Programming Language is easy, i want it to handle it on the DB side, BTW i am using C#, however i want to let the DB do the majority of the work.